# Get SLF4J loggers for given package

Tags: spring-boot, logging, logback, slf4j

For my current application, I am attempting to get the loggers for the given package. However, after multiple attempts still I am unable to do that. I will add the sample code block for what I've been trying so far.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory; 

  private final Logger logger;

  private TestUtils(String thePackageOrLoggerName) {
    ILoggerFactory iLoggerFactory = LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
    this.logger = iLoggerFactory.getLogger(thePackageOrLoggerName);
  }
```

However, the logger I get from the above code does not work. It has the name attribute with the package I've given but it doesn't contain any loggers within the package. In the above example I am only based on `SLF4J` and does not relay on `Log4j2` or `Logback` because I want this implementation to be independent of underlying logging framework.

However, I could accomplish what I want to do in my previous attempt but I did use `logback-core` library. I will also add the code block for that as well for a better understanding of what I am going to do.

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;

  private final Logger logger;

  private testUtils(String thePackageOrLoggerName) {
    LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
    this.logger = context.getLogger(thePackageOrLoggerName);
  }
```

With the above implementation, my logger contains all the logger instances for the given package. I want to accomplish the same behaviour without using the `logback-core` and only using `SLF4J` related libraries. Can anyone give me insights to proceed further and it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using lombok instead and add `@Slf4j` above the class.
Now you can do like:

```
LOGGER.info("Text");
LOGGER.getName();
LOGGER...{etc}
```

Will make things super easy.  You just need to add `@Slf4j` above any class you want a logger in. And it will do the rest for you.

If you only wanted a single logger. You can make a single logger class this way. And just create methods to call the logger inside the class

```
@Slf4j
@NoArgsConstructor
@Component
public class TestLogger() {
    public void logWarning(String warn){
        LOGGER.warn(warn);
    }

    public void logError(String error){
        LOGGER.error(error);
    }
}
```

Then just Autowire this class into each area you need it.

All code is untested and was written in the text field provided here.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok

Comment: Thanks for your response! I clearly understand what you mean and that is not my real issue here. In my case what I have is a package name. As an example -  "com.example.logging.test". Then I have SLF4J logger factory and I am looking for a way to get the loggers for the given package.